# checksum error when using HDFS copyFromLocalFile

Tags: hadoop, checksum

```
        try {
        conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
        //conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://zal:9000");
        hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path src = new Path(urlTmpFile);
        Path dst = new Path(ipPath);
        hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(false, true, src, dst);
        //hdfs.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("updateLocalFileToHDFS failed" + e.getMessage() );
    }
```

The error info is checksum error is really confused me!

```
12/09/07 06:19:18 INFO fs.FSInputChecker: Found checksum error: b[0, 20]=687474703a2f2f77772e62616964752e636f6d0a
org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumException: Checksum error: url.txt at 0
```

Are there any tips or examples on how to do this?

Comment: how did you import this file into hdfs , if I may know

Comment: Thank you.I download the file from HDFS ,and than modified it ,than update to the HDFS, this cause checksum error.

Comment: I found the reason. Thank you.when download file from HDFS,will new a .crc file in localfilesystem.and when you update ,FSInputChecker will check .crc file ,it will check consistency of the content if there exits crc files, else if it fails, then it will stop uploading the files .

Comment: kool , please like the comment